# Convert from Int32MultiArray into vector (roscpp)

Tags: ros, std-msgs, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to simply put array from the `std_msgs` into `vector<double>`

```
 void setdot(const std_msgs::Int32MultiArray::ConstPtr& arr){
    vector<double> tmp;
        tmp.push_back(arr[0]);
        tmp.push_back(arr[1]);
        tmp.push_back(arr[2]);
}
```

error: invalid use of void expression if i compile it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226564/convert-from-int32multiarray-into-vector-(roscpp)/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone who is interested I had a look at [this](http://alexsleat.co.uk/2011/07/02/ros-publishing-and-subscribing-to-arrays/), which converts the std_msgs into an Array but this is how the vector is done:

```
    void setdot(const std_msgs::Int32MultiArray::ConstPtr& array){
    vector<double> tmp;
    for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = array->data.begin(); it != array->data.end(); ++it)
    {   
        tmp.push_back( *it);
    }
    //do sth with tmp ..
    }
```

Furthermore check if the input message is not empty, which might occur on the first callbacks as it was in my case.
 Otherwise `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` might happen.

---

Originally posted by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) with karma: 748 on 2016-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1